# pd.merge() order of operations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that share the same index column `full_idx`.

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'idx': [1, 2, 4, 8], 'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'full_idx': ['Cust1', 'Cust2', 'Cust4', 'Cust8']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'idx': [2, 4, 9, 11], 'B': [99.1, 11, 13, 0], 'full_idx': ['Cust2', 'Cust4', 'Cust9', 'Cust11']})
```

I use this index column to create a numeric version of it (`idx`), and set that as the df's index.

```py
df1 = df1.set_index("idx")
df2 = df2.set_index("idx")
```

Whenever I join, I prefer to go through the index as these data frames are pretty large in size, except that I always suffer from duplicate column names. So, in the case of `full_df1`, `full_idx` was duplicated. Now if I opt to join also on `full_idx (just like in` full_df2`), that problem goes away.

My question is regarding the order of operations of `pd.merge()`: does having a column in the `on=[]` field override the index join and instead it will merge based on the common column specified in the `on=[]` field? Am I losing my merge based on the index performance boost by assigning an `on=[]` column?

```py
full_df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, right_index=True, left_index=True, sort=False)
full_df2 = pd.merge(df1, df2, right_index=True, left_index=True, on=["full_idx"], sort=False)
```

full_df1:

```py
     A full_idx_x     B full_idx_y
idx                               
2    b      Cust2  99.1      Cust2
4    c      Cust4  11.0      Cust4
```

full_df2:

```py
     A full_idx     B
idx                  
2    b    Cust2  99.1
4    c    Cust4  11.0
```

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, on=['idx','full_idx'])`?

Comment: I'd always want to merge based on the index (for the performance boost)